# Node.js server works partly

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

In api folder I have 3 js files (calls.js, meetings.js, statistics.js). All files look the same:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

var knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
      host : 'host',
      user : 'user',
      password : 'password',
      database : 'database'
    }
});

***knex functions***

module.exports = router
```

all of them added in index.js file in the same way:

```
app.use('/api/calls', require('./routes/api/calls'))
app.use('/api/statistics', require('./routes/api/statistics'))
app.use('/api/meetings', require('./routes/api/meetings'))
```

For some reason meetings.js make troubles: 
1. If delete all knex functions from meetings.js - everything works;
2. If delete the line `app.use('/api/meetings', require('./routes/api/meetings'))` from index.js - everything works;
Otherwise browser says: "This site can’t be reached... ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

Full code of meetings.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

var knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
      host : 'host',
      user : 'user',
      password : 'password',
      database : 'database'
    }
});


app.post('/newMeetingDay', (req, res) => {
  const city = req.body.city
  const date = req.body.date
  const scheduled = req.body.scheduled
  const happened = req.body.happened
  const adults = req.body.adults
  const children = req.body.children
  if (!city || !date || !scheduled || !happened || !adults || !children){
    return res.json({Error: 'details are missing'})
  }

  knex('MeetingDays').insert({City: city, Date: date, Scheduled: scheduled, Happened: happened, 
                              Adults: adults, Children: children}).then(data => {
    return res.json({Done: 'new meeting day saved'})
  }).catch(err => {
    return res.json({Error: err})
  })
})


module.exports = router
```

Does anyone know what can be a problem?

Comment: An error in meeting.js by the sound of it. I would suggest posting the all code for `meetings.js` as the error is probably in the knex functions. Going to be hard for anyone to help otherwise.

Comment: @GillesC thanks, posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a problem: in `meetings.js` the function should be `router.post` and not `app.post`